# How to to exclude automatically Dev only tables from Dacpac for Azure Pipeline CI/CD?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-sql-database, dacpac

I have Azure Devops for Azure databases using Dacpacs.
I can easily deploy schema from Dev to Test and Prod.

However I have a issue. Dev databases have several Dev only tables that I don't want to deploy to Test and Prod.

Excluding certain tables manually with Visual Studio have resulted to human errors and certain non wanted tables have been deployed to prod.

It there are solution for making sure that Dev only tables are automatically excluded from Dacpac?

Possible to automatically filter if table name starts with "Temp*"?

Comment: Why not take them out of the project altogether?  Default setting is they won’t be dropped.  You can also exclude from build in the individual script properties - “Do not build” but I think you’re better off just removing them.

Answer (score -1):

No, you won't be able to request that it just include certain object kinds. Yes, you can ask it to exclude certain object types (/[p:ExcludeObjectTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017)), allowing you to filter to exactly what you want while eliminating anything else. Using the DacFx API's programmatic paradigm, you can accomplish more targeted/convenient things, but it requires programming code.

You can use sqlPackage.exe to limit the modifications by using the /p:ExcludeObjectTypes argument to indicate the kinds you don't want to deploy.

Use the following as an example:/p:ExcludeObjectTypes="StoredProcedures;ScalarValuedFunctions;TableValuedFunctions"

The following is a list of potential ExcludeObjectTypes arguments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.objecttype?view=sql-dacfx-150